# Data Normalization and Column Name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of x-ray diffraction data that will be continuously updated and I would like to make some changes to it in R. The dataset is composed of a series of xy files that I compile into a big spreadsheet. The idea is to have the y, called I_filename, of each xy file normalized and added to a new column named I_filename_N. I managed to make the normalization process work by using

```
XRD_DATA$N <- as.data.frame(lapply(XRD_DATA[2], normalize))
```

in which normalize is a function defined as

```
normalize <- function(x){(x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))}
```

Each xy file looks like this

```
 theta_filename   I_filename
    5.00  12
    5.02  17
    5.04  15
    5.06  14
    5.08  18
    5.10  20
    5.12  17
    5.14  14
    5.16  17
    5.18  18
    5.20  15
```

With my code I managed to get the new column with the normalized data. However, the column name is not as I wanted, it became "N$I_filename", instead of I_filename_N. Also, if a add more columns to the speadsheet, I have to update the formula for normalization every time.

So my two questions are:

1. How can I modify the code for normalization so that the new column with the normalized data gets named "I_filename_N"?
2. Is it possible to automated the code so that the normalization is always applied to every "I_filename" column instead of having to add the "number" of the column to the code? Also, I can change the name of the columns if necessary, like "N_I_filename" if it's possible to automate based on columns starting with "I_...".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try just `XRD_DATA$I_filename_N <- normalize(XRD_DATA$I_filename)`. Your current code is adding a nested dataframe rather a new column.

Comment: To your second question, try `library(dplyr); XRD_DATA %>% mutate(across(starts_with("I_filename"), normalize, .names = "{.col}_N"))`.